# passing jquery datetimepicker to sqlite database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have a Jquery DataTimePicker implemented and do not know how to pass this field into my Database.

Just need some basic help, not even sure where to begin. Any help is greatly appreciated

This is what i have as far as code goes.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :start_date %>
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a name to input field, e.g., `<input id="datetimepicker" name="start_date" type="text" >`.  Then in your controller action you can access this value as: `params[:start_date]`.

Comment: It also helps to format the datetime input via the jquery call so you don't have to use ruby to format it too much in the controller etc.

Comment: thanks for that guys! so in my controller i have this for creating a new appointment        def new   @appointment = Appointment.new ....what do i put here?